# Angular animation trigger but not animating anything

Tags: angular, animation

I want to defined a simple animation. But it doesn't work.

```
export const routeAnimation: AnimationEntryMetadata =
  trigger('routeAnimation', [
    state('in', style({
      opacity: 1
    })),
    state('out', style({
      opacity: 0,
      display: 'none'
    })),
    transition(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('200ms ease-out')]),
    transition('in => out', animate('1050ms ease-in'))
  ]);
```

The :enter transition works as expected. However, the in => out transition is launched (the "done" callback is executed after 1050ms) but the component just desappears suddenly after this 1050ms timing without fadein.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
After settings the css `display` property to block inside the component stylesheet, all start working fine.